# How to keep alive the connection in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, session, time, plsqldeveloper

I am using PL/SQL Developer 11.0.4.1774. In my work, I need to use database whole day. Sometimes, during 30-60 minutes, I do not use ide and when I need to use it again, it requires reconnection.

I do not want to reconnect, is there any way to keep the connection alive whole day?

Comment: The dba may have you in a resource consumer group that stops inactive sessions after X minutes. If you don't want to have to reconnect, keep working :)

Answer (score 14):

Go to Tools --> Preferences and click "Check connection".  It pings the database every 60 seconds, making the session active and avoids idle session disconnects caused by profiles.

[image]

**NOTE:** This question and answer are for Allround Automations PL/SQL Developer. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12999811/409172) if you're looking for Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: I have the setting `OFF` and it's work ok. don't have the problem that OP reported... the settings is for `Check Connection.
When this option is enabled, PL/SQL Developer checks every 60 seconds if your database connection is still alive. If your session is killed or the server is shutdown, PL/SQL Developer will automatically logoff.
`

Comment: @are That's because your profile is has IDLE_TIME set to UNLIMITED.  Most likely the OP's DBAs set their IDLE_TIME to a finite value due to some security policy.  This PL/SQL Developer feature is poorly named and described, but it will definitely keep the session active enough to evade the profile limit.

Comment: Awesome - I missed that setting. Much better than my answer :)

Comment: This doesn't look at all like my 19.2.0.206 Tools - Preferences

Comment: @Toolkit You are probably using "Oracle SQL Developer", which is a different program than "PL/SQL Developer".

Comment: @Toolkit what you're looking for is a little extension called "keepalive" which does the exact same thing in Oracle SQL developer - https://github.com/scristalli/sql-developer-keepalive

Comment: Some tip on how to install above plugin.
Donwload the jar file.
https://github.com/scristalli/sql-developer-keepalive/releases

Download the above jar and in your PL/SQL dveloper go to  **HELP  > CHECK FOR UPDATES > "INSTALL from Local  Files"***..... Browse to jar and install it.

Comment: @Reddymails The names are very similar, but "SQL Developer" and "PL/SQL Developer" are two different products. I added a link to my answer for "SQL Developer" since this a common mistake.

Answer (score 3):

you need check 'IDLE_TIME' and 'CONNECT_TIME' setting for your user profile

```
select * from dba_profiles
  where resource_name in  ('IDLE_TIME','CONNECT_TIME')
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6010.htm

> If a user exceeds the `CONNECT_TIME` or `IDLE_TIME` session resource
>   limit, then the database rolls back the current transaction and ends
>   the session. When the user process next issues a call, the database
>   returns an error.

I have PL/SQL Developer opens for days and don't have the issue
my PL/SQL Dev `Tools-Prefernces-connection` settings are:

- Session Mode = Multy Session
- Check connection = unchecked
- Logoff with open transaction = Commit

and  TIME settings are:

```
    PROFILE RESOURCE_NAME   RESOURCE_TYPE   LIMIT
1   DEFAULT IDLE_TIME   KERNEL  UNLIMITED
2   DEFAULT CONNECT_TIME    KERNEL  UNLIMITED
```

Comment: it's possible that the OP's DBAs have set things up so that connections are dropped after they've been idle for a certain period. I doubt that changing the above settings will affect how long the session is idle for.

Comment: I have the same settings with you but as I said, I have problem.

Comment: updated - check IDLE and CONNECT time settings for your profile

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the Reconnect plug-in so at least reconnecting can be a simple button-press.
2. Possibly against the intention of the DBA (if the issue is due to profile/resource manager settings), but you might try setting a Sessions window (or other report/query etc) to auto-refresh every 25 minutes or so.

Edit: I see on the [Bar Solutions website](http://bar-solutions.com/) the developer has moved Reconnect from "Plugins" to "Old Plugins". At my current client site I can't install plugins, so I can't tell whether it still works at the moment.