# How can I fetch unlimited records in dropdown in .NET MVC through API?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, oracle-sqldeveloper, dropdown

I have tried by adding 10000 records in table, it is working fine for the same and able to add fetch without any error. But when tried to add more than 10000 records in the same table it is giving service time out error. As service itself is throwing timeout error. I dont't want to increase the timeout in web.config.

I am using Oracle SQL developer as a database engine and default connection string with entity framework.

I tried to add this piece of code in controller, but it is not working.

```cs
var result = this.Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
```

[This is the error i am getting while trying to add more than 10000 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsibE.png)

Comment: Maybe it's just bad design. How do you expect your user to pick between 10000 items? Let them type a few characters and then do search instead.

Comment: I agree with Palle - displaying that many records in a list is a terrible idea. Assume the end-user can scroll through 10 records per second. It would take them nearly **17 minutes** to scroll through a list of `10_000` items. Let the user search for the item they want instead.

Comment: I agree with Palle that it's probably not a good idea, but can you add your connection strings to the question? 
What database engine are you using?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL developer @AAP

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your comment you are using an Oracle DB. The error you are getting is a timeout which will be defaulted to X by whatever database provider you are using.

If you are using .NET Framework 4.8 this link *should* help:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection.connectiontimeout?view=netframework-4.8

Another link which might help:

- [How can I keep Oracle SQL Developer from closing the DB connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013431/3658380)

Here is the official documentation from Oracle:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3.2/odpnt/ConnectionConnectionTimeout.html